# Design a better API interface to pass a struct from one class to another class

Tags: c++, api

I am a strong believer of the following design philosophy:

1> Services should be implemented as close as possible where the data is stored.

2> Getter and Setter are evil and should be used carefully.

I rather NOT argue above two arguments here and assume they have their edges.

Here is the challenge I am current facing. I have two classes (i.e `AComputer` and `A`) where AComputer provides some services for A and A holds all fundamental data members.

Fact: I am not allowed to combine `AComputer` inside `A` due to the system design. I knew, it has broken my point 1> where computation should stay with data.

When passing data from `A` to `AComputer`, we have to pass 10(approximately) individual parameters and so it is better to design a structure to do that otherwise the constructor list will grow crazy. Most of the data stored in `AComputer` are direct copies those of stored in `A`. We chose to store those data inside `AComputer` because other functions in `AComputer` also need those variables.

Here is the question( I am asking for best practice considering API maintenance & modification):

1> Where should we define the pass-structure `PassData`?

2> Should we provide getter/setter for struct `PassData`?

I have provided a sample code as follow to illustrate my question in details. It is best that I can find a real work open-source API that has addressed the same issue so that I can learn from it.

If you look at private `PassData m_data;` defined in class `AComputer`, I do this in purpose. In other words, if we change the underlying implementation of `AComputer`, we can replace `PassData m_data;` with individual variables or something else but NOT break the interface of `PassData`.
So in this design, I do NOT provide a getter/setter for the struct `PassData`.

Thank you

```
class AComputer
{
public:
    struct PassData
    {   // int type just used as an illustration. Real data has different types,
        // such as double, data, string, enum, etc.
        // Note: they are not exact copies of variables from A but derived from them
        int m_v1;
        // from m_v1 to m_v10
        //...
        int m_v10;
    };

    // it is better to store the passed-in data since other functions also need it.
    AComputer(const PassData& pd) : m_data(pd) {}

    int GetCombinedValue() const
    { /* This function returns a value based the passed-in struct of pd */ }

private:
    PassData m_data;    
};

class A
{
private:
    int m_i1;
    // from m_i1 to m_i10
    // ...
    int m_i10;
    // from m_i11 to m_i20
    // ...
    int m_i20;

    boost::shared_ptr<AComputer> m_pAComputer;

public:
    A()
    {
        AComputer::PassData aData;
        // populate aData ...
        m_pAComputer = boost::shared_ptr<AComputer>(new AComputer(aData));
    }

    int GetCombinedValue() const
    {
        return m_pAComputer->GetCombinedValue();
    }
};
```

Comment: Are the arguments involved truly all `int` (or all of any one type)? If so, I think I'd just pass a `std::vector<int>`. If you want to access those by name, I'd define an enum in `AComputer` that provides names for the subscripts, so you could use `argument[m_i1]` instead of `argument[0]`.

Comment: Good point. The arguments are full of different types, such as int, double, string, date, etc. I will update my OP to clear up the confusion.

Comment: What?! You have two design philosophies, and for some reason just *have* to break number 1. Now you ask us if it is a good idea to break number 2? What did I miss here?

Comment: I learn those two good design practice. However, in the real world, we have to do some compromise. Here is a good example to illustrate that. I list all what I have to do and then ask for some good design practice based on the limitation.

Comment: Is the AComputer::PassData known and fixed or can it change from execution to execution?
Anyway, it doesn't really matter. I'd create a separate class for the PassData with add data members private and proper set/get methods. It will provide better encapsulation and access control, in case your program will have to be made multithreaded.

Comment: @ilya1725, the reason why I propose to define `PassData` as a nested class of AComputer, it should only be used when passing data to AComputer. Your comments can still be implemented in above case. Just make variables private and provide getter/setter. The point is that it really is worth doing so?

Answer (score 11):

I think it is better clarify a couple of points before start, you said:

> If you look at private PassData m_data; defined in class AComputer, I
>   do this in purpose. In other words, if we change the underlying
>   implementation of AComputer, we can replace PassData m_data; with
>   individual variables or something else but NOT break the interface of
>   PassData.

This is not true, PassData is part of your interface! You cannot replace PassData without breaking client code, because you require PassData in the constructor of AComputer. PassData is not implementation details, but it is pure interface.

Second point that needs clarification:

> 2> Getter and Setter are evil and should be used carefully.

Correct! But you should know that a POD (Plain-Old-Data struct) is even worst. The only advantage of using a POD instead of class with getter and setter is that you save the trouble to write the functions. But the real issue is still open, the interface of your class is too cumbersome and it will be very difficult to maintain.

Design is always a trade-off between different requirements:

**A false sense of flexibility**

Your library is distributed and a lot of code is using your class. In this case a change in PassData will be dramatic. If you can pay a small price in runtime you can make your interface flexible. For example the constructor of AComputer will be:

```
AComputer(const std::map<std::string,boost::any>& PassData);
```

Have a look at boost::any [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/any.html). 
You may also provide a [factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) for the map, in order to help the user to create the map easily.

*Pro*

- If you do not required a field any more the code is unchanged.

*Cons*

- Small runtime price.
- Lose the compiler type safe check.
- If your function requires another mandatory field you are still in trouble. The client code will compile but it will not behave correctly.

Overall this solution is not good, at the very end it is just a fancy version of the original one.

**Strategy Pattern**

```
struct CalculateCombinedValueInterface
{
   int GetCombinedValue()=0;
   virtual ~CalculateCombinedValueInterface(){}
};

class CalculateCombinedValueFirst : CalculateCombinedValueInterface
{
   public:
       CalculateCombinedValueFirst(int first):first_(first){}
       int GetCombinedValue(); //your implementation here
   private:
       //I used one field but you get the idea
       int first_;
};
```

The client code will be:

```
CalculateCombinedValueFirst* values = new CalculateCombinedValueFirst(42);

boost::shared_ptr<CalculateCombinedValueInterface> data(values);
```

Now, if you are going to modify your code, you shouldn't touch already deployed interface. The Object Oriented solution for this is provide a new class that inherites from the abstract class.

```
class CalculateCombinedValueSecond : CalculateCombinedValueInterface
{
   public:
       CalculateCombinedValueFirst(int first,double second)
           :first_(first),second_(second){}
       int GetCombinedValue(); //your implementation here
   private:
       int first_;
       double second_;
};
```

The client will decide if upgrade to the new class or to stay with the existing version.

*Pro*

- Improve your interface without break client code.
- You are not touching existing code, but you introduce new functionality in a new file.
- You may want to use the [template method design pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method) if you want a smaller granularity control.

*Cons*

- Overhead of using virtual functions (basically few picoseconds!)
- You cannot break existing code. You have to leave the existing interface untouched and add a new class to model different behavior.

**Number of parameters**

If you have a set of ten parameters input in one function, it is very likely that these values are logically related. You may collect some of these values in classes. Those classes may be combined in another class that it will be the input of your function. The fact that you have 10 (or more!) data members in a class should ring a bell.

The [single responsibility principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/srp.pdf) said:

There should never be more than one reason for a class to change.

The corollary of this principle is: your class has to be small. If your class has 20 data member is very likely that you will find a lot of reason to change it.

**Conclusion**

After you have provided an interface (any kind of interface) to the client you cannot change it (a good example are all the deprecate features in C++ that compilers need to implement for years). Pay attention at the interface that you are providing even implicit interface. In your example, PassData is not implementation details but it is part of the class interface.

The number of parameters is a signal that your design needs to be reviewed. It is very difficult change a big class. Your classes should be small and depend to other classes only via an interface (abstract class in C++ slang).

If your class is :

1) small and with just one reason to be changed

2) derived from an abstract class

3) other classes refer to it using a pointer to the abstract class

Your code can be changed easily (but the already provide interface has to be preserved).

If you do not fulfill all these requirements, you will be in trouble.

**NOTE:** requirements 2) and 3) can change if instead of provide dynamic polymorphims the design is using static polymorphims.

Comment: let me answer your questions one by one. Point1> If I decide to change the internal implementation of `AComputer`, I don't have to change `PassData`. Method1> change/replace the definition of variable `m_data`(i.e. It can point to a new struct). Method2> You gave a good example how to provide new functions without breaking the existing code. Similarly, we can introduce `PassDataV2` here without breaking the existing interface. That is the main reason why I said "I don't know whether getter/setter for PassData is necessary". `AComputer` has two levels to adapt to new changes.

Comment: Point2> I totally agree with you. In fact the core issue here is that the passing-data structure is huge(10~20). The class is used to compute complex mathematical model that does need so many different parameters in order to make it work. The main concern of the question is how/where we should define that `PassData` for good practice and code maintenance. -Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You might consider refactoring to use a pattern object--this object's sole purpose would be to contain the parameters for the method call.  For more detail: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object

Comment: I got similar ideas in the OP. As you can see, we introduced a `PassData` class that is used to pass a group data from A to AComputer. To me, the link doesn't provide new information that can improve the current code. -Thx

Answer (score 0):

In a normal class design, all member function have the this pointer passed as an implicit parameter so that they can access the data members:

```
// Regular class
class SomeClass
{
public:
    // will be name-mangled by the compiler as something like: 
    // void SomeClass_getValue(const SomeClass*) const;
    void getValue() const 
    {
        return value_; // actually: return this->value_;
    }

private:
    int value_;
};
```

You should mimic this as much as possible. If for some reasons you are not allowed to merge the AComputer and A classes into one clean class, the next best thing would be to let AComputer take a pointer to A as a data member. In every member function of AComputer, you would then have to explicitly use the getter/setter functions of A to access the relevant data members.

```
class AComputer
{
public:
    AComputer(A* a): p_(a) {}

    // this will be mangled by the compiler to something like
    // AComputer_GetCombinedValue(const Acomputer*) const;
    int GetCombinedValue() const
    {
         // in a normal class it would be: return m_i1 + m_i2 + ...
         // which would actually be: return this->m_i1 + this->m_i12 + ...
         // the code below actually is: return this->p_->m_i1 + this->p_->m_i2 + ... 
         return p_->get_i1() + p_->get_i2() + ...       
    }

private:
    class A;
    A* p_;
};

class A
{
public:
   // setters and getters

private:
   // data only, NO pointer to AComputer object
}
```

So in effect, you have created an extra level of indirection that creates the illusion to users that AComputer and A are part of the same abstraction.

Comment: This is exactly how the legacy code does. The class ends with 20~40 functions that solely function to provide getter/setter. I also have considered to use friend but friend introduces class-coupling issue though.

Comment: @q0987 If you think of `AComputer` in terms of the interaface, and `A` in terms of the implementation, this is the best you can do. Creating yet another class PassData simply obscures your intent because then you have yet another level of indirection. The authors of your legacy code should have done integrated the classes.

Comment: your proposed method introduces circular dependence and I try to avoid. Also without introducing PassData, the constructor will end up with ~10 pass-in parameters.

Comment: @q0987 See my edited post. `class A` should break the cycle by not having a pointer back to `AComputer`. This way, A is a behaviorless aggregate. Let's face it, your current design is broken, so if you don't want to change anything about `AComputer` and `A` (that should form a single integrated abstraction in any meaningful design), then   you have your work cut out for you!

Comment: I cannot agree more with you on the point that "the current design is broken'. Based on your updated post, the class `A` is simply a data container. However in my project, `A` contains all variables and also includes many calculation logics. Just for some of these computation, the team wants to let the class `AComputer` do. That introduces the issue I listed in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Using PassData instead of 10 arguments is good if you have total control of all AComputer clients. It has two advantages: you need to make fewer changes when you add another piece of data to pass, and you can use assignment to struct members on the caller site to make meaning of each "argument" clear.

However, if other people are going to use AComputer, using PassData has a serious drawback. Without it, when you add 11th argument to AComputer constructor, the compiler will detect an error for users who did not update the actual argument list. If you add 11th member to PassData, the compiler will silently accept the structure where the new member is garbage, or, in the best case, zero.

In my opinion, if you use PassData, having getters and setters would be an overkill. "C++ Coding Standards" by Sutter and Alexandresku agrees with that. Title of item #41 is: "make data members private, **except for behavourless aggregates (C-style structs)**" (emphasis is mine).